# Comparing a column against an entire table of ranges?

Tags: sql-server-2008

Sorry if this has been asked before, I've searched and have been unable to find any answers.

I have 2 tables in a DB, TableA has a column we'll call ID (a 4-digit integer), and TableB has 2 columns of 4-digit integers that form a range.

What I would like to do is check to see which ID's can be found in **any** range, so that if ID had

1
5
7
9,
and TableB had ranges
4-6,
100-101,
and 3000-4000, 5 would be properly matched as belonging to a range. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT *
  FROM TableA a
    WHERE EXISTS
    (
        SELECT 1 
          FROM TableB b
            WHERE  a.ID BETWEEN b.ID1 AND b.ID2
    )
```

Comment: Thanks! I feel extremely foolish now.